# MySQL query in CellFormatting event in datagridview runs slow using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have problem with CellFormatting event in datagridview.

Everytime I add the following codes, it runs very slow.

```
disconnect()
connect()
cmd=New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT idnum FROM tblmanhours GROUP BY idnum HAVING SUM (basic) > 48", con)
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader

While dr.Read
  If Me.dgvmanhours.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText = "ID_No" Then
    If e.value = dr.GetString(o) Then
       e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Crimson
       e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If
  End If
End While
```

What I wanted to do is to color the cells returned by the query. The output of the above codes was correct, but it runs very slow everytime I debug it. And whenever I commented those codes, it runs fast.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the redraw on each change is slowing things down, so this might help.

```
Me.dgvmanhours.SuspendLayout()
While dr.Read
   ...
End While
Me.dgvmanhours.ResumeLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache the query results in a DataTable and then query the local datatable from the event.

If all you are doing is setting color just make a single pass over the DGV (or a row/cell) with each data change.  `dgv(10, 10).Style.BackColor = Color.Crimson`